# Second level menu dropdown Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I am developing a site with a dropdown menu done with CSS and jQuery.

When I click to open it, and the menu is larger than the bottom of the page, the scrollbar automatically increases. But when I open a sub menu with hover effect, the scrollbar does not increase and the content is hidden.

This only happens on google Chrome, IE and Firefox appears normally.

In order to visualize the problem, open www.rspneus.com.br click on the menu labeled "MARCA" and then leave the mouse over the item "KUMHO".

Thanks regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
position:relative;
```

i have tested and it is work on chrome as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a class to the grey drop-downs (e.g the one that appears when you hover over KUMHO), and then add the styling below:

```
.yourNewClass {
 overflow: auto;
 max-height: 200px; /*you can alter this*/
}
```

that way when the height of the drop down exceeds 200px, a scroll bar will appear inside the drop down so that the user can scroll up and down within it.

Comment: that resolve a part of problem, have a way to resize the page scrollbar?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by resizing the page scrollbar, but what you also need to do in order to restrict the height of the main drop down is add the same styling to that, see below:

`#select03options {
 overflow: auto;
 max-height: 200px; /*you can alter this*/
}`

Comment: I think I not was clear.

I would like to have the same effect I have in the IE or Firefox, the scrollbar increase when the content is shown.

Thank you so much for all the helping